# Add to a list and using a subset of that list to call a function

Tags: java

I have 2 functions. function1 returns 100 (or less) items in one call. function 2 takes a list with size of 150 items as input.
I have to call funciton1 in a loop and use that input to call function 2. My current logic looks like this:

'''

//START

```
    int f2FetchSize = 150;
    boolean allDataNotFetched = true;
    List<Item> inputToFunciton2 = new ArrayList<>();
    
    while (allDataNotFetched) {
        List<Item> items = function1();
        if (items.size() == 0) allDataNotFetched = false;
        items.forEach(item -> {
            inputToFunciton2.add(item);
            if (inputToFunciton2.size() == f2FetchSize) {
                List<Item> temp = new ArrayList<>();
                temp.addAll(inputToFunciton2);
                function2(temp);
                inputToFunciton2.clear();
            }
        });
    }
```

//END
'''

Looking for a better way to write this. Using streams(?) or any other way.
I have not tried to run this yet as I am still coding the rest of the functionality.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please define "better".

Comment: what is the termination condition for the while loop?

Comment: @devReddit .. I got this line code wrong "if (items.size() == 0) allDataNotFetched = true;" should be "if (items.size() == 0) allDataNotFetched = false;"

Comment: @tgdavies - code that is more concise or easier to read or uses less variables or all of these.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sublist to maintain the items you are getting from `function1`.
First of all, divide responsibilities. create a `void` function and pass the `items` list to the function to populate data from `fucntion1()`:

```
public void manageDataFromFunction1(List<Item> items) {
    List<Item> tempList = function1();
    items.addAll(tempList);
    if (tempList.size() == 0 && items.size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Function1 size empty");
        function2(items);
        items.clear();
    }
}
```

After that, you can do as follows to achieve your goal:

```
int f2FetchSize = 150;
List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();    
while (true) {
    manageDataFromFunction1(items);
    if (items.size() == 0) {
        break;
    } else if (items.size() >= 150) {
        function2(items.subList(0, f2FetchSize));
        items.removeAll(items.subList(0, f2FetchSize));
        System.out.println("Items size after removal: " + items.size());
    }

}
```